# THEAD Issues in Chrome : Handling Multiple Tables Across Multiple Pages

Tags: google-chrome, html-table

Working specifically with Google Chrome (version 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit)), I've run into a problem where my table headers are suddenly overlapping each other (in print view) when there is a page overflow of row data from one table and a new table of data being created. It appears as though there is a conflict of the thead when multiple tables are present across multiple pages.

Most solutions I've found refer to a single table header repeating on multiple pages, but I have yet to find any discussion about header handling of multiple large tables in a single report.

Is there a solution to this, or is this a bug introduced in the recent Chrome update?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've tracked it down to a known bug in the recent update... 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826#

It looks like this has been an ongoing issue for some time. Comment 69 mentions the exact issue that I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best temporary workaround IMO:

```
thead {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```